# why cassandra throws exception in select query?

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra db ,while i use select at some times i get this exception?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/cqlsh", line 1001, in perform_statement_untraced
    self.cursor.execute(statement, decoder=decoder)
  File "bin/../lib/cql-internal-only-1.4.0.zip/cql-1.4.0/cql/cursor.py", line 81, in execute
    return self.process_execution_results(response, decoder=decoder)
  File "bin/../lib/cql-internal-only-1.4.0.zip/cql-1.4.0/cql/thrifteries.py", line 131, in process_execution_results
    raise Exception('unknown result type %s' % response.type)
Exception: unknown result type None
```

can any one explain why this exceptions occur and also i get Internal application error.

what this error message actually means?

**EDIT:** I get this error for the first time, next time onwards its running correctly.I dont get why it is so?

```
//cql query via cqlsh
select * from event_logging limit 5;
```

Comment: Add the query, it will be easier to get an accurate answer.

Comment: cqlsh:event_logger> select * from  event_logging limit 5;I get this error for the first time, next time onwards its running correctly.I dont get why it is so?